# Prepend a command with instant DNS resolve

Tags: terminal, dns

I need fake a DNS before running a command in my terminal.

Like a `export` environment, have a way to do something like this with DNS?

```
fakedns kafka=172.28.128.19 
kafkacat -C -b 172.28.128.19:9092 -t logging_application_access
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Kafka broker is using "kafka" as its advertised.listener and "kafka" is not available in DNS, you could add an entry to /etc/hosts on the client machine:

`1.2.3.4   kafka`